# Passing ImageData via postMessage doesnt work on chrome

Tags: javascript, web-worker, webassembly, postmessage

EDIT:

It ended up being very relevant information that this only happens when the ImageDate comes from WASM, I dont know why this would matter. If anyone knows anything about this behaviour and can explain why this happens with WASM-originated ImageDatas only an answer would be highly appreciated.

I have been developing a website with no weird JS shenanigans, no weird libraries etc.
But when trying to pass an ImgData object from a webworker to the main thread using postMessage in chrome, I get null on the other end.

ImageData is supposed to be supported by the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) which is what postMessage uses ([postmessage docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage)).
This works in Firefox, and doesnt give any crash/throw/warning in chrome, it just doesnt pass through the data.

```
console.log(ret); // properly displays the ImageData with data, width and height.
postMessage(ret); // no throw or anything
```

```
myWorker.onmessage =  function(e) {
    console.log(e); // e.data==null
    // use e.Data as ImageData, which crashes.
}
```

If I pass in just a random string for testing it does work properly. Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

I have tried all the error events for webworkers, but non of them get called, so there is no

Comment: are you sending the constructed ImageData object or the underlying imgData.data? eta: looks like you're sending the whole thing, I suggest trying to send the array and the width/height separately

Comment: The ImageData, if I send the imgData.data that would just be the Uint8ClampedArray that backs the imageData losing the size, I could try, I didn't think of that. But if that works why wouldn't the ImageData itself work?

Edit: THIS WORKS!!! I am very much puzzled on why jsut the ImageData doesnt work, but somehow passing the buffer + size separately and reconstructing it on the main thread works. You can post that as an answer if you want and I can mark it as the solution

Comment: [Works here](https://jsfiddle.net/tz1r268g/) for me in Chrome 87.0.4280.88 on macOs

Comment: Yes very weird, that also works for me. I tried making the image very big to see if that was the issue but no. I think I figured it out though, if the backing array is created in wasm, then it does not work, but if I create a new ImageData that is not backed by an originally wasm buffer it works. EDIT: after copying the backing buffer in JS, it does in fact work.

Comment: So what about you [edit] your question so it has all the information in it and can both receive more attention of someone facing the same issue, and maybe receive better answer/solutions?

Comment: wow that's a real nice way of asking! I will definitely do that after such a nice request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why Chrome isn't working but I suggest you try sending the underlying `imageData.data` array and the `width` and `height` separately.

```
const {data, width, height} = imageData;
postMessage({data, width, height})
```

You can then re-construct it at the receiving end.